# Issue passing form data to php variable. Variable seems empty

Tags: php, mysql, post, sql-update

I'm a noob at PHP/MySQL. I've been looking around a lot but I can't figure out what's going wrong. Purpose of the script: update the value of `item 1` and `item 2` in the database of user with userID entered in txtUser.

I get my script working when I use a "fixed" value near userId in my query. However, when I try to use a variable ($player), it doesn't work. Seems like my variable is empty...

HTML:

```
<body>
   <form id="form1" action="http://www.something.com/TestScript1.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

    <div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" title="SAVE">SAVE</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="txtUser" name="txtUser" type="text" />
        <input id="txtItem1" name="txtItem1" type="text" />
        <input id="txtItem2" name="txtItem2" type="text" />
    </div>

</form>
</body>
```

PHP :

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";
$player = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['txtUser']);
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("connection to server failed");
mysqli_select_db($connection,$database) or die ("couldn’t select database");

$item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['txtItem1']);
$item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['txtItem2']);

$query = "UPDATE table SET item1=$item1, item2=$item2 WHERE userId=$player";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query)
or die ("couldn’t execute update query: ".mysqli_error($connection));
echo "<h4>Data saved in the database</h4>";
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put this line

```
$player = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['txtUser']);
```

After $connection

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("connection to server failed");
```

Like

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("connection to server failed");
$player = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['txtUser']);
```

Because you using $connection variable in mysqli_real_escape_string even before its initialised

Answer (score 1):

$connection is not defined for line

```
$player = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['txtUser']);
```

please move this line after you create $connection

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("connection to server failed");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "database";



    $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("connection to server failed");
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$database) or die ("couldn't select database");

    /* The $conn object must be declared before first / any calls to mysqli_real_escape_string */
    $player = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txtUser']);
    $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txtItem1']);
    $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txtItem2']);

    /* Values in query should be encapsulated in quotes if they are strings.. are they? */
    $query = "UPDATE `table` SET `item1`='$item1', `item2`='$item2' WHERE userId='$player';";

    /* Try not to reveal too many details in the event of an error, reduce the attack surface if possible! */
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die ("update failed: ");
    echo "<h4>Data saved in the database</h4>";
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```